# Get currently logged on user id in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC with AddHttpContextAccessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a web app with user management, the main problem is that admins can delete themselves and thus crashing the application. I had the idea of getting the current user id registered so if the one that is currently logged tries to delete himself, it blocks that action.

The real problem resides in that I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong trying to get the under ID (a string)

I added `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in the `Startup` class
and added

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
{
        _options = options;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

in the applicationDbContext.

Finally on the class where the dealing user's method is, I created

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
```

and then I tried to use this snippet of code:

```
var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

but that returns null. The whole context of the method is as follows:

```
public async Task DeleteUsuarioAsync(String id)
{
        var strategy = _context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
        await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () => {
            using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var user = _context.Users.Where(u => u.Id.Equals(id)).ToList().Last();
                    var _listRoles = await _userRole.getRole(_userManager, _roleManager, id);
                    await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, _listRoles[0].Text);
                    var dataUser = _context.TUsers.Where(u => u.IdUser.Equals(id)).ToList().Last();
                    var idUser = user.Id;
                    var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                    if (idUser != "25c986cb-d0d3-41aa-aae6-cfcd2279f458")
                    {
                        if (userId == idUser)
                        {
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _context.Remove(dataUser);
                            _context.SaveChanges();
                            _context.Remove(user);
                            _context.SaveChanges();
                            transaction.Commit();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }

                    //if (idUser == "25c986cb-d0d3-41aa-aae6-cfcd2279f458")
                    //{
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    _context.Remove(dataUser);
                    //    _context.SaveChanges();
                    //    _context.Remove(user);
                    //    _context.SaveChanges();
                    //    transaction.Commit();
                    //}
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
        });
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? Perhaps there's another way to prevent the user from deleting himself?

**Edit**: I forgot to add that the method inst on a controller, but a class I created called lusuarios. Seems like all tutorials I checked online all do it on the controller.

Comment: Are you looking for `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` ? Or some other claim that you added during login?

Comment: Be sure you have DI the `IHttpContextAccessor`(like what you did in ApplicationContext) in the controller which have `DeleteUsuarioAsync` method.

Comment: @Rena thank yu so much, if I say this couldnt let me sleep I would be telling the truth. You were right about having to repeat the process in there.

Answer (score 1):

On top of what I did I added `IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor` to the class like this :

```
public Lusuario(
             UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            IWebHostEnvironment environment,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _context = context;
            _environment = environment;
            _userRole = new LUsuariosRoles();
            _uploadimage = new LUploadimage();
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
```

then I had to add it on: HomeController, PerfilController and on my class Details, like this on all of them

```
 public HomeController(
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            ApplicationDbContext context,
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
            IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            //_serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _usuario = new Lusuario(userManager, signInManager, roleManager, context, null, httpContextAccessor);
        }
```

then `var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;` no longer returned null and I could compare the currently logged user ID with the one that was getting deleted.